# Keep numbers only in python using Lambda

Tags: python

I am trying the following lines to keep only the digits

```
>>> s = "H3ll0 P30P13"
>>> filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), s)
'303013'
```

But what I got is not '303013' but I got `<filter at 0x1888b671408>`. I am using Spyder IDE

Comment: `filter` method in python returns `iterator` that is filtered from the input. we can get the vaue by converting to list and join with space `"".join(list(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), s)))`. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. The same answer like @Franco Piccolo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), s))
```

Comment: Thanks @MichaelSzczesny just updated the simplified answer.